# How to convert a flatten list back to tensor while retaining the location?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor

Suppose I have a tensor like the following:

```
x = torch.tensor([[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
         [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]])
```

and I want to extract the position of the lowest 3 values, which is 1, 2, and 2 in this example.

So I first flatten x and get the index:

```
v, i = torch.topk(x.flatten(), 3, largest = False)
```

`i` output `tensor([0, 5, 1])`, which is the index that I want, but it is not in the index of the original tensor shape. What I am looking for is [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], and [0, 1, 0].

How can I revert the location of the index?

Answer (score 0):

There is a functionality in `Numpy` which seems handy in creating the desired output. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find the `Pytorch` equivalent and I believe there isn't any yet! I suggest using this function:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
x = torch.tensor([[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
         [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]])
v, i = torch.topk(x.flatten(), 3, largest = False)
print(np.unravel_index(i, x.size()))
```

output:

```
(array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 1, 0]), array([0, 0, 1]))
```